# Joining three tables and displaying value using php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have used join and was able to get output table in phpmyadmin using this query :

```
$query    =    "SELECT members.usn, members.name, events.ename FROM members JOIN participant ON members.usn = participant.usn JOIN events ON events.eid = participant.eid WHERE members.usn='.$usn.'";
$result    =    $conn->query($query);
```

The Output was

| usn | name | ename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7DC18CS005 | John | Robo Wars |

I used PHP to display this in my homepage for specific user by maintaining usn in their SESSION.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo  $row[0];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo  $row[1];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo  $row[2];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo "No Members[Connected DB]";
}
```

But the output gives me
`"No Members[Connected DB]"`
instead of expected output which is

| usn | name | ename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7DC18CS005 | John | Robo Wars |

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the session is not empty? Try debugging with `print_r($_SESSION)`

Comment: @ruleboy21 The SESSION has been set during login and its not changed anywhere till logout. Tried Debugging to verify.
The Solution given by you below worked! Thank you mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the query. Looks like you are trying to concatenate `$usn` to the query but you got it wrong.

Change

```
$query = "SELECT members.usn, members.name, events.ename FROM members JOIN participant ON members.usn = participant.usn JOIN events ON events.eid = participant.eid WHERE members.usn='.$usn.'";
```

To

```
$query = "SELECT members.usn, members.name, events.ename FROM members JOIN participant ON members.usn = participant.usn JOIN events ON events.eid = participant.eid WHERE members.usn='$usn'";
```